# Tokbox: subscriber seeing yourself in webcam

Tags: web, webrtc, tokbox

I want to know if tokbox API is possible in some session, the subscriber see yourself  in webcam, on the side of the page.

The examples I have be all of publisher and subscribers (not seeing themselves.)

Answer (score 2):

If your purpose is to test your own camera before publishing, you don't have to go through OpenTok to do so. You can use the browser + camera directly.

Here are two good articles from Vonage Video API (Tokbox):

[How can I create a pre-call test in my app?](https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029413792-How-can-I-create-a-pre-call-test-in-my-app-)

[Waiting Room and Pre-Call Best Practices With Vonage Video API](https://learn.vonage.com/blog/2021/07/15/waiting-room-and-pre-call-best-practices-with-vonage-video-api/)

Answer (score 1):

You can see a preview of own camera stream using `publisher` object.

Here is an Android example:
https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/blob/564fab50d7f16e2ca42bb59fe6226cf287cade24/Basic-Video-Chat/app/src/main/java/com/tokbox/sample/basicvideochat/MainActivity.java#L77